# Angular template strict mode throws error when trying to pass a number to @Input x: string | number using two way binding

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I want to update my application to use Angular's [template Strict mode](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-mode) by setting `"strictTemplates": true` inside `tsconfig.json`. After running `ng serve` with the new config, I got a weird error.

I have a shared component that is used in a lot of places

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-shared-component',
  ...
})
export class SharedComponent {
  @Input() selectedId: string | number;
  @Output() selectedIdChange = new EventEmitter<string | number>()
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  ...
}
```

and passing `<my-shared-component disabled="true">` throws an error, which is fine.

The problem comes into play when I try to pass a `number` into the `@Input() selectedId: string | number;`, i.e.:

```
export class OtherComponent {
  myNumberId: number;
  ...
}

<my-shared-component [(selectedId)]="myNumberId">
```

And an error is thrown:

> TS2322: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'

I don't want to replace the type of `myNumberId` with `string | number` because it's also used in another component that has an `@Input id: number` (and must be a number). Also, `myNumberId` comes from the server and I know that is a number, so I think it will lead to poor design if I replace it with `string | number`.

I also don't want to use the [strictAttributeTypes](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#troubleshooting-template-errors) config to false because afterwards `<my-shared-component disabled="true">` will no longer throw an error.

I was wondering if there exists some typescript utility type (or something similar) to make  `@Input() selectedId: string | number` accept only strings or numbers, without forcing the variables from the parent to be `string | number`. Or can I do something else to fix the problem?

Comment: Is the two-way binding nescessary here? It makes sense to me that your code fails, since you wouldn't want `app-shared-component` to assign a `string` to your `number` input.

Comment: Can you reproduce this? Clearly, I can assign a `number` to a `number | string`. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hggbyn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @MikeS. It works. I had some more occurrences this is why I initially said that it doesn't work. So yes, it makes sense to fail... But I really need the two way binding.  The ugly solution is `[selectedId]="myNumberId"; 
 (selectedIdChange)="myNumberId= $any($event)"`. Do you think it can be found a better one?

Comment: My other thought was using a simple pipe that would parse the string to a number if nescessary, but while testing that I noticed that you apparently cannot pipe a property when used in a two-way binding... the more you know :-) The solution in the accepted answer sems just fine though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it rightly throws an error - the output `EventEmitter` will emit either `string` or `number`, which will try to assign a value to your strictly typed number.

What you could do is try separating a setter and getter in your `OtherComponent`:

```
_myNumberId: number;

get myNumberId(): number {
    return this._myNumberId;
}

get myNumberId(value: string | number): number {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      // This is a stub, you might want to go with something else like parseFloat()
      // or just throw.
      this._myNumberId = parseInt(value, 10);
    } else {
      this._myNumberId = value;
    }
}
```

This partially persists the `number` for the check types were values is fetched and still allows for setting the value from either `string` or `number`, so it will remove the compilation error. But it's not a good solution since it looks like a code smell, and it "loosens" the type checking on the setter.

If you take a step back and look at the bigger picture - perhaps you should define what an "Id" is in your application, and use that type in a generic component? Something along the way of:

```
export type MyId = string | number;
```

Then, your component could use generic extending that type, which will do the strict type checking:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-shared-component',
  ...
})
export class SharedComponent<T extends MyId> {
  @Input() selectedId: T;
  @Output() selectedIdChange = new EventEmitter<T>()
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  ...
}
```

This will allow for assigning either `string` or `number` as Input / Output in two-way binding and coercing the type to a single one of those in both places. And later on, if you decide you need to apply an additional logic to the `Id` itself, you can change it in one place (type definition) and see if it violates any type checks.

Of course you can always NOT define the type and do it like this:

```
export class SharedComponent<T extends string | number> {
```

but it seems you might want to enforce this in a few different places as well, so a custom value type seems like a good way to go.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amabvm) using the generics approach that correctly assigns both `string` and `number` values in two-way binding, but fails to assign a different type (`Date`).
If you remove the date assignment, it will compile correctly.

Comment: Cool, the generic types approach is very cool. Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try replacing `string | number` with `string & number`.

And you can also try sending it like this :

```html
<my-shared-component [(selectedId)]="+myNumberId">
```

Comment: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: Try the solution separately, not both at once

Comment: I tried and got the same result

Comment: For the second on I forgot to tell you to use `@Input() selectedId: number`